# Heroku recently started giving deploy error "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE" during Webpack build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack, webpack-4

Our deploy code hasn't changed, and our Webpack version (`"webpack": "^4.41.0"`) hasn't changed, and deploys still work successfully for other (non-Heroku) servers.

However, just a couple days ago, Heroku deploy stopped working with this error:

```
2878 <s> [webpack.Progress] 70% building 4114/4114 modules 0 active
2879 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2880 npm ERR! errno 1
2881 npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build-heroku: 'npm run clean && webpack --progress --bail --env dist -p'
2882 npm ERR! Exit status 1
2883 npm ERR!
2884 npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build-heroku script.`
```

Our `/package.json` has:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "cd frontend && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
```

And our `/frontend/package.json` has:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist/*",
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack --progress --bail --env dist -p && rm -r prod 2>/dev/null || : && mv dist prod"
}
```

So why does Webpack build only get to 70% in Heroku now? Has anyone else seen this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we weren't reading the log in full. There was errors in the middle of it which weren't appearing at the end. We literally had to search the raw log file for the word "**error**".

For example:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/tmp/build_e65fff75f8ffc7b45670e320e578bd35/frontend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core'
```

The solution involved several steps:

1. Installing some of the modules (ie npm install x)
2. Adding this block to Webpack config:

   node: {
           fs: 'empty',
           net: 'empty',
           tls: 'empty',
           dns: 'empty'
         }
3. Stopping using the ruby image in our **.gitlab-ci.yml** file:
   [image]